# Reduce duplication FosRest annotations

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using [Fos RestBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html) that helps me implement some annotations for my Rest API resources.

The fact is that I don't really like the huge block of annotations that should be defined above my function...where I'm using `query param fetcher` to get some data such `query` and `category`.

How can I create **one Symfony annotation** that includes the hole block of `@FOSRest\QueryParam` annotations? I would like the new solution to help reduce the code, separate code, and decoupling it.

This is my function:

```
    /**
     * @param ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher
     *
     * @return int[]
     *
     * @FOSRest\QueryParam(name="query")
     * @FOSRest\QueryParam(name="articleReference", requirements="\d+")
     * @FOSRest\QueryParam(name="category", requirements="\d+")
     * @FOSRest\QueryParam(name="memberCategory", requirements="\d+")
     * @FOSRest\QueryParam(name="supplier", requirements="\d+", nullable=true)
     * @FOSRest\QueryParam(name="published", requirements="(0|1)", nullable=true)
     * @FOSRest\QueryParam(name="withoutCoefficient", requirements="(0|1)", nullable=true)
     * @FOSRest\QueryParam(name="zipCode", requirements="\d+", nullable=true)
     * @FOSRest\QueryParam(name="memberCategoryStrict", default=0, requirements="(0|1)")
     * @FOSRest\QueryParam(name="orphan", requirements="(0|1)", nullable=true)
     * @FOSRest\QueryParam(name="articleType", requirements="article|catalog", nullable=true)
     * @FOSRest\QueryParam(name="withImage", requirements="0|1", nullable=true)
     * @FOSRest\QueryParam(name="withTechnicalSheet", requirements="0|1", nullable=true)
     *
     */
    public function getArticlesStatsAction(ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
    {
     //
     }
```

I want to implement an annotation called `@GetArticlesStats()` for eg. where the final result should look like this:

```
/**
 * @param ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher
 *
 * @return int[]
 *
 * @GetArticlesStats()
 *
 */
public function getArticlesStatsAction(ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
{
//
}
```